# How to install Google's ScaNN library on M1 mac?

Tags: installation, knn

I wanted to to use ScaNN for one of my projects but couldn't install it on my M1 air.

I have tried `pip install scann` but it doesn't work.
I tried compiling their open sourced code on my machine by installing the correct versions of tensorflow and bazel but receiving some certification error.

ps: I had to switch to google colab workspace to use ScaNN.

Comment: Without seeing the errors you get its hard to help you. "Doesn't work" and "some certifiation error" is not that helpful.